# Return a value from express js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Below code is my express middleware call

```
var c = app.use(myMiddleware());

console.log(c);
```

// the middleware function

```
module.exports = function() {

    return function(req, res, next) {
       var b =  {'A' : 1};
        next();
    }

};
```

In above code console.log print console once application started.

I want to return/pass a value from middleware to my express application. please any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Set anything you want to use in request scope to req object.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var b =  {'A' : 1};
  req.b = b;
  next();
});
```

then you can use it in your request handler:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.b);
});
```

Comment: I have edited my solution. Please check if it works.

Comment: app.get not working but if we use below code then it working

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Middleware", req.b);
});

Comment: yes your right but req.b is undefined when I request localhost:3000/test but app.use(function) is working when I request localhost:3000/ I am not understand what happening

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var c = app.use(myMiddleware({
  callback: function(c) {
    console.log(c)
  }
}))
```

// the middleware function

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    var b =  {'A' : 1}
    next()
  }
}
```

---

Or this:

```
var x = myMiddleware()
var c = app.use(x.function)
console.log(x.something)
```

// the middleware function

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  options && options.callback && options.callback('Hello world!')

  return {
    function: function(req, res, next) {
      var b =  {'A' : 1}
      next()
    },
    something: 'Hello world!',
  }
}
```

Comment: Second example not work out for my need because 'Hello world' got print in app start. Need to get the value on request.